# jQuery remove array element and refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think it's too late at night for me to figure this out. Basically, I have a master array. I loop over it and remove an element if I find it. I do this for 4 elements.

In the end I want to display any leftover elements. The problem is that I'm not refreshing my array correctly after I remove an element.

Here's the code I'm using which I feel is too much brute force and not enough elegance.

```
var masks = ["valueOne","valueTwo","valueThree","valueFour","valueFive"]; 

    $.each(masks,function(key,value){ 
        if("valueOne" === value){
            // do something
            masks.splice($.inArray(value, masks),1); 
        }else if("valueTwo" === value){
            // do something
            masks.splice($.inArray(value, masks),1);
        }else if("valueThree" === value){
            masks.splice($.inArray(value, masks),1);
        }else if("valueFour" === value){
            // do something
            masks.splice($.inArray(value, masks),1);
        }
    });
    console.log( masks.toString() );
```

I'd expect the console to log "valueFive" but it doesn't. It logs this:

```
valueTwo,valueFour,valueFive
```

What's the correct way to refresh an array after updating it? Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15386005/5087125

Comment: Use map : http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/hhcj98jr/

Comment: @pvg - that is a super nifty trick - thanks!

Comment: @fument np. For something like this, the diff methods using filter/indexof shown there are probably worth considering too since you'll probably be able to tell how they work 3 months from now when you start wondering what on earth the code you wrote does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `$.each()` is iterating through the array by its indices.

```
(function(key,value){ ... })( 0, "valueOne" );
(function(key,value){ ... })( 1, "valueThree" );
(function(key,value){ ... })( 2, "valueFive" );
```

`"valueTwo"` and `"valueFour"` are skipped because `.splice()` modifies the array, shifting them to an index that has already been visited by `$.each()`.

```
masks[0] === "valueTwo"
masks[1] === "valueFour"
```

---

A quick solution to this is to provide a clone of the Array to iterate over, one that remains unaltered throughout, so you can safely modify the original.

```
$.each(masks.slice(0), function (key, value) {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the code dude...

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var masks = ["valueOne","valueTwo","valueThree","valueFour","valueFive"]; 
var count = 0;
    $.each(masks,function(key,value){ 
        //console.log( masks.toString() );
        key = key - count;
        //console.log(masks[key]);
        if("valueOne" === masks[key]){
            masks.splice($.inArray(masks[key], masks),1); 
            count++;
        }
        if("valueTwo" === masks[key]){
            masks.splice($.inArray(masks[key], masks),1);
            count++;
        }
        if("valueThree" === masks[key]){
            masks.splice($.inArray(masks[key], masks),1);
            count++;
        }
        if("valueFour" === masks[key]){
            masks.splice($.inArray(masks[key], masks),1);
            count++;
        }
    });
    console.log( masks.toString() );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way would be to use array.filter method of JavaScript. 
Filter expects a function and removes an element if this function returns false.

```
mask.filter(function(elem, index, array) {
    if(elem==="value") return false;
    return true;
}
```